# Loop through nested hash in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, controller, nested

What I’m trying to do is loop through a hash and save certain key’s values to the database. This hash has nested keys, and I’m struggling to find a suitable way to loop through it.

First, I’m parsing the JSON of photos (from 500px API), and putting the response into terminal:

```
def index
  @photos = JSON.parse(get_access_token.get('/v1/photos/search?term=california').body)
  p @photos
  save @photos
end
```

The response I get in console is all okay and looks like this. (I’ve cut it down so it doesn’t take up too much room):

```
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "total_pages": 50,
  "total_items": 8263,
  "photos": [
    {
      "id": 4930535,
      "name": "Bike",
      "description": "",
      "times_viewed": 28,
      "rating": 27,
      "created_at": "2012-02-10T00:39:03-05:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 4930206,
      "name": "Rain",
      "description": "",
      "times_viewed": 1,
      "rating": 59.7,
      "created_at": "2012-02-10T00:04:09-05:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 4930202,
      "name": "California",
      "description": "",
      "times_viewed": 100,
      "rating": 58.2,
      "created_at": "2012-02-10T00:05:25-05:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

I’m then trying to loop through the `photos` and save the `name`, `description` and `times_viewed` to the db, using this save method.

```
def save photos

  photos.each do |photo|
    p = Photo.new(:name => photo["photos"]["name"], :description => photo["photos"]["description"], :times_viewed => photo["photos"]["times_viewed"])
    p.save
  end

end
```

The trouble is that the photos key is nested, and it throws this error in terminal:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer):
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:18:in `[]'
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:18:in `block in save'
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:17:in `each'
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:17:in `save'
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:10:in `index'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the photos array out of your json response and iterate over that. This way you only have one layer of hash keys to reference:

```
json_response['photos'].each do |photo|
  Photo.create name: photo['name'], description: photo['description'], 
    times_viewed: photo['times_viewed']
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`photos["photos"]` is an array so you need to specify the index before `name`. The implementation of your save method isn't completely clear, but I believe your parameters for the new method should have the form:

```
:name => photo["photos"][index]["name"]
```

You're getting a conversion error since the compiler is trying to convert `name` into an index.